# Open conjectures in number theory that is easy to do some programming for

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I have a to do a project in number theory that we are assigned that we should do some programming for that is not the collatz conjecture, so any suggestion would be really great.

Comment: The Goldbach conjecture is easy to program.

Answer (score 1):

How about an investigation of the primality of the Euclid numbers: 
$$\displaystyle E_n=1+\prod_{i\leq n}p_i;$$
 where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime... and the testing of them using the probabilistic Miller-Rabin Test?

Answer (score 0):

That is a nice question!! Is from a month ago, but just in case, the Fortunate numbers are also an interesting and easy to code conjecture (depends on the capacity of your computer)

[Fortunate numbers](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortunate_number)

Good luck with your search!